# Fix __init__() error when using association_proxy on self association relationship on Flask app

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm developing an app with flask that uses a self referencing association relationship between two users but I can't make it work as when I try to create the association I get and **init**() error saying that im sending 2 arguments to the association proxy when just added 1.

I have tried to implement the self referencing association through a dual association_proxy as posted at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/OeLrx74p5vY by Mychel and Simon and got the error in question, then I tried to implement the self referencing association through a dual relationship as posted on [SQLAlchemy configuring many-to-many relationship to self using Association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261383/sqlalchemy-configuring-many-to-many-relationship-to-self-using-association) by SingleNegationElimination and got a KeyError with not enough info to debug

```
class tutorship(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tutorship_tablename'
    """Reference table of tutors and students"""
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    studentId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    professorId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    subject = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable = False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False)
    rating = db.Column(db.Float, nullable = True)
    timeAgreed = db.Column(db.Float, nullable = False)
    comments = db.Column(db.Text, nullable = True)

    # Original try
    student = db.relationship('User', primaryjoin=(studentId == User.id), backref='to_student')
    professor = db.relationship('User', primaryjoin=(professorId == User.id), backref='from_professor')

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__='user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False)
    surname = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)

    # Original try
    tutors = association_proxy('to_student', 'professor')
    students = association_proxy('from_professor', 'student')

        # Second try
    #students = db.relationship('tutorship', primaryjoin=(id == tutorship.studentId), backref='to_student')
    #professors = db.relationship('tutorship', primaryjoin=(id == tutorship.professorId), backref='from_professor')

@app.route('/<professorId>/<studentId>/<subject>/<date>/<timeAgreed>')
def tutorshipConfirmed(professorId, studentId, subject, date, timeAgreed):
    if (current_user.is_authenticated) and (str(current_user.id) == professorId):
        student = User.query.filter_by(id = int(studentId)).first()
        professor = User.query.filter_by(id = int(professorId)).first()
        date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        # Original try
        student.tutors.append(professor)

        # Second try
        #student.professors.append(professor)
        db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

I expected to create an instance of the self-reference association between two users but got those errors when tried.

Comment: Is the desired result to create a new `tutorship` instance when the a request is made to the `tutorshipConfirmed()` view?